# p:chart label overflows frame when label size is increased, how to hide the overflow?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts

I have developed a pie chart in primefaces and when the label size increases the plotted label goes out of the chart frame. I want to hide the label in chart.I have added my code below

**XHTML**

```
<p:chart type="pie"id="InFlowTotalPieChart" 
         rendered="#{CompositeAction.LandingActionBean.renderinflowTotalPieChart}"
         model="#{CompositeAction.LandingActionBean.inflowTotalpieChartModel}"
         style="width:290px ;height:205px;">
   <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
           listener="#{CompositeAction.LandingActionBean.openInPieDialog}"></p:ajax>
</p:chart>
```

**Java**

```
inflowTotalpieChartModel = intCategoryInflowTotalPieChart(foreActDetailList);
inflowTotalpieChartModel.setTitle("Total In-Flow");
inflowTotalpieChartModel.setLegendPosition("ne");
inflowTotalpieChartModel.setFill(true);
inflowTotalpieChartModel.setShowDataLabels(true);
inflowTotalpieChartModel.setDiameter(150);
inflowTotalpieChartModel.setMouseoverHighlight(true);
inflowTotalpieChartModel.setShadow(true);
inflowTotalpieChartModel.setDataFormat("value");
```

**ScreenShot**
[image: Pie Chart ScreenShot]

Comment: any answers for this question pls